# ResetNeeded: Cannot call `env.render()` before calling

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm running with the following versions:

```
python 3.8.10
gym==0.21.0
gym-notices==0.0.8
```

I'm trying to run the simple example of Taxi (gym) from `jupyter notebook`:

```
import gym
env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env
env.render()
```

And get the following error:

```
ResetNeeded: Cannot call `env.render()` before calling `env.reset()`, if this is a intended action, set `disable_render_order_enforcing=True` on the OrderEnforcer wrapper.
```

If I add the reset command:

```
import gym
env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env
env.reset()
env.render()
```

I'm getting new error:

```
ssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [33], line 4
      2 env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env
      3 env.reset()
----> 4 env.render()

File ~/Repo/py38Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/wrappers/order_enforcing.py:51, in OrderEnforcing.render(self, *args, **kwargs)
     46 if not self._disable_render_order_enforcing and not self._has_reset:
     47     raise ResetNeeded(
     48         "Cannot call `env.render()` before calling `env.reset()`, if this is a intended action, "
     49         "set `disable_render_order_enforcing=True` on the OrderEnforcer wrapper."
     50     )
---> 51 return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/Repo/py38Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/wrappers/env_checker.py:53, in PassiveEnvChecker.render(self, *args, **kwargs)
     51 if self.checked_render is False:
     52     self.checked_render = True
---> 53     return env_render_passive_checker(self.env, *args, **kwargs)
     54 else:
     55     return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/Repo/py38Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/utils/passive_env_checker.py:316, in env_render_passive_checker(env, *args, **kwargs)
    310     else:
    311         assert env.render_mode is None or env.render_mode in render_modes, (
    312             "The environment was initialized successfully however with an unsupported render mode. "
    313             f"Render mode: {env.render_mode}, modes: {render_modes}"
    314         )
--> 316 result = env.render(*args, **kwargs)
    318 # TODO: Check that the result is correct
    320 return result

File ~/Repo/py38Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/toy_text/taxi.py:290, in TaxiEnv.render(self)
    288     return self._render_text()
    289 else:  # self.render_mode in {"human", "rgb_array"}:
--> 290     return self._render_gui(self.render_mode)

File ~/Repo/py38Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/toy_text/taxi.py:308, in TaxiEnv._render_gui(self, mode)
    305     elif mode == "rgb_array":
    306         self.window = pygame.Surface(WINDOW_SIZE)
--> 308 assert (
    309     self.window is not None
    310 ), "Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen."
    311 if self.clock is None:
    312     self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

AssertionError: Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen.
```

How could I run Taxi (gym) example from notebook ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can still help.
However, I figured this out by myself. The solution was to just install "pip install gym[toy_text]" first and include 'render mode':

```
import gym env = gym.make("Taxi-v3", render_mode="rgb_array").env env.reset() env.render()
```